# What is meaning of ducking here

Tags: meaning

A sentence is "he's been ducking me" or "You duck your responsibilities" What does it mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ducking in these contexts normally means avoidance, literally lowering one's head, and often more of the body, to avoid being seen, or being hit by something. A boxer might duck to avoid being hit by his opponent's fist.

Ducking in other contexts can mean to be immersed partly, or totally, in water usually unwillingly.

Duck: verb
gerund or present participle: [ducking](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ducking)

1. lower the head or the body quickly to avoid a blow or missile or so as not to be seen.
   "spectators ducked for cover"
2. push or plunge (someone) under water, either playfully or as a punishment.
   "Rufus grabbed him from behind to duck him under the surface"
   "she was ducked in the river"

[dictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

In the way that the bird-ducks put their heads below the water, one who ducks gets out of sight to avoid contact or responsibility.